# DevExpress MemoExEdit does not show the first line of my text until down arrow pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, devexpress, multiline

I needed a TextBox in C# UI with the capability of showing the multiline content if needed.  Once the down arrow or ellipsis (located at the inner edge of the text box)is pressed, then a dialog pops up and either allows the user to type more text or shows the already saved multiline text.

To that end , after research I found MemoExEdit from DevExpress.  Now I have everything I need except the textbox(MemoExEdit) does not show anything until the down arrow is clicked. in other words the text inside the box is blank actually just a blue A shows up regardless of my content.   Thanks for any help how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer :  Set the MemoExEdit's Properties.ShowIcon property to false.